# Bash command to clear the VSCode integrated terminal scrollback on Windows 10?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, xterm

I'm happily running [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) bash in VSCode 1.53.2 on Windows 10 with:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

The "Terminal: Clear" command (`workbench.action.terminal.clear`, which I have bound to Control-L) clears not only the screen but *also the scrollback buffer, as expected*, so trying to scroll up does nothing because there is nothing to show.

How can I reproduce this with a shell command?

The `clear` command does *not* clear the scrollback, neither does `reset`.  These commands work by outputting escape sequences to the screen.  Since the terminal thinks it is "TERM = xterm-256color", the relevant escape sequence should be the one output by the shell command

```
printf "\e[3J"
```

which works on all other xterm emulations (and is part of `clear`'s output).  In VSCode it does not clear the scrollback but, oddly, resurrects one screenful of previously cleared scrollback.

Comment: In my vscode, `printf "\e[3J"` does clear the scrollback.

Comment: Thanks.  What is your VSCode integrated terminal default shell  (`terminal.integrated.shell.windows`)?

Comment: I have `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",`